# UE4 How to make character face direction of the movement

Tags: unreal-engine4, blueprint

G'day, I'm new to coding in general and I was wondering if there was a way to make the character face in the direction of movement using blueprint coding, I know about the orient rotation to movement check box but I'm trying to make the character face in the direction they're moving and then when you press a button or use the right analog stick start facing in the direction of the mouse or analog stick, and that doesn't seem possible with the orient rotation to movement activated but does work with it off but now I can't figure out how to orient to movement with coding, btw this is a top-down project

[Here is the event graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/roJBC.jpg)

[Here is the code that I attempted to make the character orient to rotation movement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r29BX.jpg)

[This one I got from a video to make the character face the mouse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/77q8n.jpg)

Comment: Instead of taking photos of the screen, [take a screenshot](https://www.take-a-screenshot.org/) or - in this case - [create a pastebin of your nodes](https://blueprintue.com/).

Comment: Would that be better to help me?

Answer (score 0):

You can just check the boolean bUseControllerYaw which is also in Blueprint character. Use control rotation yaw